# Filling an selectList through cshtml

Tags: jquery, razor, postback, html-select

Im trying to update a `select`list, depending on the value in another `select`. While calling the server. Is there a way to do this without JSON. I don't mind doing a full `Postback`of the site, but whould prefer another solution.

Im using csHTML and jQuery.

the code:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <select name="SelectProductGroup" id="SelectProductGroup">
        <option value="0" disabled selected>
            select group
        </option>

        @{
            foreach (ProductGroup vg in productGroupList)
            {
                <option value="@vg.id">
                    @vg.name
                </option>
            }
       }
    </select>

    <select name="UpdateProduct" id="UpdateProduct">
        <option value="0" disabled selected>
            select product
        </option>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" name="btn" value="updateProduct" />
</form>


<script>
    $().ready(function () {
        $('#SelectProductGroup').on('change', function () {
            var options = {
                @{
                    int temp_ID = 0;
                    if(Request["SelectProductGroup"] != null)
                    {
                        temp_ID = int.Parse(Request["SelectProductGroup"]);
                    }
                    int counter = 0;
                    List<Product> productList = Product.getListBy_ProductGroup(temp_ID, connection);
                    string result = "";

                    foreach(Product v in productList)
                    {
                        result += "val" + v.id + " : " + v.name;

                        if(counter < productList.Count())
                        {
                            result += ",";
                        }
                    }

                    <text>
                        @result
                    </text>
                }
            };

            $.each(options, function (val, text) {
                $('UpdateProduct').append(
                        $('<option></option>').val(val).html(text)
                    );
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

JSON whould be a great solution. Just don't seems to be able to get my head around it. Therefore im looking for alternatives to a JSON solution ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery has a [.load](http://api.jquery.com/load) method that allows you to make an AJAX request and add the response into a containing element.

Eg:

```
$('#UpdateProduct').load('http://myserver.com/getProductsAsHtml?id=XXX');
```

Just make sure that webpage returns nothing but content that should go inside the `<select>` element, eg:

```
<option>Product 1</option>
<option>Product 2</option>
```

You would use this inside the change event handler for the SelectProductGroup element:

```
$('#SelectProductGroup').on('change', function() {
  var id=$(this).val();
  $('#UpdateProduct').load('http://myserver.com/getProductsAsHtml?id=' + id);
});
```

Comment: how whould the getProductAsHTML look like?

Comment: The .load() will insert exactly what the page returns into the contents of the second select, so it should be a .cshtml that does a foreach around an <option value="@Model.Value">@Model.Text</option> or something like that. No <body> or <head>, just the list of <option> tabs

Answer (score 2):

JSON is simply a way of serializing data for transfer between (typically) a web server and a web browser. In order for you to take advantage of it in the way that most websites do, you would have to do the following:

1. Have a server web page that implements your getListBy_ProductGroup() function as an AJAX method that returns the JSON encoding of your List result. Seeing as you are using MVC, you would use WebAPI for this, perhaps implementing it as http://myserver.com/api/products?id=XXX (there is a whole school of thought called REST devoted to organising your web api).
2. On the web browser, you would would wire up a JavaScript event handler so that when the first dropdown list's value changes, an AJAX request is made to the WebAPI page, passing in the selected dropdown value as a parameter.
3. When a response to the AJAX request is received, you would have more JavaScript that replaces the contents of the second dropdown list with a new set of HTML  elements.

There are many libraries to help you achieve (2) and (3), I would recommend jQuery.

Sorry this isn't in more detail, but it's quite a large question!

Comment: Im kinda looking for a solution that doesn't implement JSON. But thanks for the great walkthrough ^^ Any other suggestions on how to update the second select list, maybe by doing a full pageload?

Comment: Ah sorry, I got hung up on the "JSON would be a great solution" bit! I have posted another answer.